# Installation failure in MS-exchange server 2013 in step 8

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

Exchange server 2013 installation i got following error message, i configure active directory and domain and assign roles for them. every time at 97% in step 8 i got this.

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
          if ($RoleStartTransportService)
          {
              start-SetupService -ServiceName FMS
          }
        " was run: "Service 'FMS' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.".
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment but this does seem valid answer. http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000577.htm

Comment: hi thanx for your concern, i already did all this, still can't resolve it.